# Want to copy document and different kind of file with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

I am trying to copy **.pdf** **.docx** and **.zip** files with a single click via batch file. Its working perfectly but the problem is it takes so much time to copy the data.For Example, If I want to copy those extension file for the **Drive D** the batch file will run to find **.pdf** first than after searching the whole drive for the **.pdf** than it will go and search for **.docx** file. I want to do that in one command if it find **.pdf** file than copy it if .docx than do the same but in one search.

**Here is the code**

```
@echo off 
    :: variables 
    /min 
    /w

    SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
    set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y 
    echo off 

    %backupcmd% "E:\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.pdf" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIEP"
    %backupcmd% "E:\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.docx" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Walima\MOVIED"
    %backupcmd% "E:\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.doc" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Walima\MOVIED"
    %backupcmd% "E:\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.zip" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Mehndi\MOVIEZ"
    %backupcmd% "E:\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.rar" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Mehndi\MOVIEZ"


    %backupcmd% "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.pdf" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIEP3"
    %backupcmd% "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.docx" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Walima\MOVIED3"
    %backupcmd% "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.doc" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Walima\MOVIED3"
    %backupcmd% "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.zip" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Mehndi\MOVIEZ"
    %backupcmd% "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\MIEMS\Dropbox\Bahria\*.rar" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Mehndi\MOVIEZ"



    @echo off 
    cls
```

I want to do something like it will go to Drive E and the specific path and copy the files in a single line of code like in the first search it will copy .pdf if found else find if docx is there yes copy it then..

It will be really helpful if you guys could help me solve this problem.

**EDITED ONE**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set backupcmd=echo
set drive=N:

SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
echo off
set backupcmd=xcopy /c /d /h /i /r /y

set "files=C:\*.pdf C:\*.doc C:\*.docx C:\*.zip C:\*.rar"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b %files%') do (
  if "%%~xi"==".pdf" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".doc" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".docx" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".zip" set "dest=Z"
  if "%%~xi"==".rar" set "dest=Z"
  if "%%~di"=="C:" if "!dest!"=="Z" set "dest=!dest!3"
  %backupcmd% "%%i"  "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIE!dest!"
)

@echo off 
cls
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this Needs some time before starting copying, because it builds the complete  list of files before working on them. But it does scan the disks just once.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set backupcmd=echo
set drive=N:
set "files=C:\*.pdf C:\*.doc C:\*.docx C:\*.zip C:\*.rar"
set "files=%files% E:\*.pdf E:\*.doc E:\*.docx E:\*.zip E:\*.rar"


for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b %files%') do (
  if "%%~xi"==".pdf" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".doc" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".docx" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".zip" set "dest=Z"
  if "%%~xi"==".rar" set "dest=Z"
  if "%%~di"=="C:" if "!dest!"=="Z" set "dest=!dest!3"
  %backupcmd% "%%i"  "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIE!dest!"
)
```

Of course, you don't need `xcopy`s Parameters `/s` and `/e` anymore.

Comment: I tried to run this code but after I double click it cmd appears and after a second it's closes and nothing is copied..

Comment: don't start a batchfile with doubleclick when testing. Start it from a cmd window to see any errormessages. Also removing `@echo off` can help, seeing, where an error occurs. And of course nothing is copied (see `%backupcmd%`) Replace it with the actual copy command, when the ouput satisfies you.

Comment: I have edited the code and I have updated it above and maybe I am making a mistake or something it will be helpful if you could look at it and point out the mistake.. and when I tried running it from cmd it's says **invalid drive specification**

Comment: sorry, I had some additional `%` in my code. No clue, where they came from. See my edited code.

Comment: I have edited the code again but still the same error **invalid drive specification**.

Comment: I think the problem is in this line **%backupcmd% "%%i"  "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIE!dest!" ** because if I replace **%drive%** with C:\ it ask me if this path is file or directory and if I press D it started to copy the files.

Comment: so, what is the value of `%drive%`? Insert an `echo "%drive%"` to check. What's it's output?

Comment: @Ebadkhan Put backslash at the end of the target destination and it will stop asking you if it is a file or directory.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks man the backslash actually solved the problem.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the help.